# Select excluding a field for a particular value in mysql query in same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Perhaps the statement is not very clear, so here you go.
We have a mysql table where we have columns like this:

```
id(key)       user_id       action
1             4832         receive_content
2             4832         click_icon
3             4832         click_image
4             4447         receive_push
5             4447         click_url
```

I want to write a select statement where we will select `user_id` and action for same `user_id` where action is `receive_content` but the final output doesn't contain `receive_content`  So the output is :

```
user_id           action
4832              click_icon
4832              click_image
```

I have been trying case but it also selects the `receive_content` field which I want to exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause to check that a `user_id` has a `receive_content` action, and then also check that the `action` for each row is not `receive_content`:

```
SELECT *
FROM actions
WHERE action != 'receive_content'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM actions a2 
              WHERE action = 'receive_content' 
                AND a2.user_id = actions.user_id)
```

Output:

```
id  user_id action
2   4832    click_icon
3   4832    click_image
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tvXNUifvenxtRLErynVUWG/0)

Comment: Hey thanks Nick , for the quick reply, this worked. Will ask you for further improvements if required ,is that ok?

Comment: @0decimal0 no problem. If the improvements are major, you should probably ask another question, but otherwise happy to respond.

Answer (score 0):

try using inner query:

```
select a.user_id, a.action
from table a
join table b on b.user_id = (select b2.user_id from table b2 where b2.action = "receive_content" and b.user_id = b2.user_id)
where a.action <> "receive_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join the table with himself , after filter row you want to keep , and select columns you want .

The solution can be this query :

```
select a.user_id,a.action 
   from actions a join actions b on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.id !=b.id 
   where 
     b.action='receive_content' and a.action != 'receive_content'
```